# Changing between full screen windows on Windows 7 Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon

I have developed a simple PoC for a Firefox addon that creates 2 ​​new windows. Once open the addon simply iterates through them calling her "activate" method to bring to the fore:

```js
var windows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;
var timer = require('sdk/timers');

var windowA = windows.open(
{
    url: "file://myfile-a.html",
});

var windowB = windows.open(
{
    url: "file://myfile-b.html",
});

var windowCache = [windowA, windowB];
var index = 0;

timer.setInterval(function() {
    if (index == 2) {
        index = 0;
    }
    windowCache[index].activate();
    index++;
}, 1500);
```

I need these 2 windows to be in full screen mode, but after the first iteration the 2 windows appear with a light blue bar at the top where the window title appears.

The funny thing is that this behavior only occurs in Windows 7. In Windows XP everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a display bug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of the code makes it full screen?

Comment: It's not in the code. I'm going full screen manually by pressing F11

Comment: That's weird behavior and shouldn't happen then.Try using `.focus()` instead of `.activate()`

Comment: I can't use `focus()` since I'm using a `BrowserWindow`. Anyway I've looked into the SDK and I thought I saw the `activate()` method in turn is calling `focus()`

Comment: Did you solve this? Doing aDOMWindow.fullScreen seems ot work for me perfectl on all but osx.